3 phase inverter with IR2110 LTspice
I am trying to implement a 3 phase inverter using IR2110 (model downloaded from infineon website) as gate drivers. I have tried to simulate the circuit using LTspice but I am having some issues.
This are gate drivers and the inverter bridge of my circuit:

I have tried to compare my circuit with a SPWM circuit found on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRag3sMNbj0)
The output current and phase to phase voltages look like this in the circuit found in youtube:

The output current and phase to phase voltages look like this in the circuit i have built with IR2110 and transistors:

At the same time the HO and LO voltages in my circuit have these voltages (which I do not think are correct since the Vout of the IR2110 goes from 10-20 V).

Can anyone help me understand why the IR2110 outputs have these values and why the phase to phase voltages look different? Thanks in advance.

Is this trapetzodial motor drive or a sinusodial general inverter?

This is a sinusoidal PWM based inverter. Thank you for your answer.

Then you need an LC output filter.

I am simulating a motor running at 300 Hz. Do you know the value of the LC filter I should use? And should I place the filter  between the inverter bridge and the motor?Thank you for your answer.

Oh, devil's in the details there. Yes, sinusoidal motor drive it is. I haven't made one myself but I would expect the C part would be required for EMI compliance but not- strictly for driving the motor to an acceptable THD/losses.

I will keep you updated if I make any progress.
